# How can we fix an extracted WinRar sequence that is in "wrong format" or "corrupted"?

Tags: iso-image, rar, winrar

I have downloaded a [sequence of RAR files](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_file.htm) from `part01.rar` to `part30.rar`. After extracting them ("select all" → "right click" →  WinRar's `Extract Here`), I had an ISO file as output.

However, when I tried to open this ISO file using WinRar, it gives the error:

> file is in wrong format or it is corrupted

What is causing this error?

How can we fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to select "part01" and select extract here and it should automatically find all the relevant parts and extract the file as needed.

As to opening the ISO file I would try opening it with another archive program like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), or by writing it to a DVD (I am assuming it is a DVD video) using a program like [CD Burner XP](http://cdburnerxp.se/) as an ISO file is typically a direct "image copy" of a DVD or CD.

If neither of these options work then it would appear that you have in fact downloaded a large amount of garbage disguised as a video file.

Comment: how do i open it as 7-ZIP? i right click -> 7zip -> open as archive but it popup: cannot open as archive.

Comment: I would try the second option and use whatever CD or DVD burning software you have available to write the file to a physical disc, I recommended CDBurnerXP but if you have any other software it should have an option along the lines of "Burn Image to Disc". I have just tested 7-zip with some ISO files I have and it appears to not be able to read files bigger than 4GB, i get a "cannot open as archive" error on a 6GB file, but it is fine with a 2.7GB file.  It may simply be a limitation in WinRar and 7-Zip.

Comment: Or get a DVD drive emulator like Daemon tools.  BTW, Windows 7 has a built in ISO to DVD burner tool. Rightclick the iso.

Comment: Actually you should be able to extract the whole file from any one part, not necessarily part 1, at least with WinRar.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that when WinRar was installed on your machine, ISO was not checked as a format for it to handle.  To correct this, you may need to reinstall WinRAR after uninstalling it.
Download WinRar from http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm and double-click on the setup file to proceed with installation - and make sure you check ISO to associate with WinRAR (when you see the select all buttom) during WinRAR setup.

After the reinstall is done, double click on the ISO file to display it's contents.

Comment: No I'm already opening it with WinRar using `right click -> open with -> WinRAR`...